# How can I get the print of all values of combinations?

Tags: java, recursive-query

For now I did the code to apply the formula, Cm,n= m!/n!(m-n)! on recursive way, but I need to print the entered values. like this:
If entered values are {J,M,L,D,P} m=5 & n=2 C5,2= 10
and generate:
JM
JL
JD
JP
ML
MD
MP
LD
LP
DP

my code actually is like this:

```
public long factorial(long n) {
    if(n==1||n==0) return 1;
    else 
        return n*factorial(n-1);
}
public long combinacionsimple(long m, long n) {
    return factorial(m)/(factorial(n)*factorial(m-n));
}
```

And in Main Class I request the values:

```
Scanner entrada = new Scanner (System.in);
    long m, n;
    Combinatoria combinatoria = new Combinatoria();
    do {
        System.out.println("Ingrese el valor de m: ");
        m = entrada.nextLong();
        System.out.println("Ingrese el valor de n: ");
        n = entrada.nextLong();
        if (n>m) {
            System.out.println("El valor de n no puede ser mayor a m");
        }
}while (n>m);

    System.out.println("Ingrese Los Elementos");
    String elementos[] = new String[(int)m];
    for(int i=0; i<elementos.length; i++) {
        System.out.println("Elemento "+(i+1)+":");
        elementos[i]=entrada.next();
    }
    System.out.println("La Combinacion de "+m+" en "+n+" es: "+combinatoria.combinacionsimple(m, n) );
```

I need to generate the combinations but I only got variations like this:

```
public void generarCombinacion(String elementos[], long m, long n, String cad ) {
    if (n==0) 
        System.out.println(cad);
    else
        for(int i=0;i<m;i++) {
            if(!cad.contains(elementos[i]))
            generarCombinacion(elementos, m, n-1,cad+elementos[i]+" ");
        }   
}
```

Please anybody can help me with this?
I Really need to do the same for Variations, Permutations & Combinations, but my problem is here in combinations

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this:

```
public static void generarCombinacion(String elementos[], int n) {
    generarCombinacion(elementos, 0, 0, n, new ArrayList<>());
}

private static void generarCombinacion(String elementos[], int ix, int start, int n, List<String> cad) {
    if (n == 0) {
        System.out.println(cad);
    } else {
        for (int i = start; i < elementos.length-n+1; i++) {
            if (ix == cad.size()) {
                cad.add(elementos[i]);
            } else {
                cad.set(ix, elementos[i]);
            }
            generarCombinacion(elementos, ix+1, i+1, n - 1, cad);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much!!!! i had to change some variables but the logical did it!!!!